# Cast from interface to child class of class implementing the interface

Tags: c++, casting

We have a Models_Manager class in our project with map of IGameObjects

```
        std::map<std::string, IGameObject*> gameModelList;
```

We add objects like this

```
Models::Sphere* sphere = new Models::Sphere();
sphere->SetProgram(Shader_Manager::GetShader("textureShader"));
sphere->Create();
gameModelList["fireball"] = sphere;
```

Later we would like to access the sphere again. To do that we would like to cast from IGameObject to Sphere. How? Thank you

inheritance:

```
class Sphere : public Models::Model
class Model :public IGameObject
```

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to use dynamic_cast

```
Models::Sphere* spherecast = dynamic_cast<Models::Sphere*>(gameModelList["fireball"]);
```